# Selecting active object to use for modifier from names in Blender

Tags: python, blender

I am trying to create a sequence of concentrical spherical shells with Blender using the script given below. The idea is to create a series of concentrical spheres, and then use the boolean operator difference to obtain the shells.

```
import bpy


mat0 = bpy.data.materials.new("hole")
mat0.emit=0.5
mat0.diffuse_color = 0.5,0.5,0.5


mat1 = bpy.data.materials.new("EO")
mat1.emit=0.5
mat1.diffuse_color = 0.0,0.0,0.8

mat2 = bpy.data.materials.new("ALK")
mat2.emit=0.5
mat2.diffuse_color = 0.5,0.5,0.0

mat3 = bpy.data.materials.new("CH")
mat3.emit=0.5
mat3.diffuse_color = 0.5,0.0,0.0

radii = [1, 1.1, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7]
mat = [mat0, mat1, mat2, mat1, mat3]
name = ["sphere0", "sphere1", "sphere2", "sphere3", "sphere4"]


for i in range(0,len(radii)): #Loop to create all the spheres, which will make up the shells of the sphere
  bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(segments=64,ring_count=32,size=radii[i],location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation=(0, 0, 0))
  ob = bpy.context.object
  me = ob.data
  me.materials.append(mat[i])
  ob.name = name[i]


for i in range(len(radii)-1,0,-1): #Transforms the spheres into shell, by the     boolean operator difference between the larger shell and the smaller one

  # Create a boolean modifier named 'my_bool_mod' for the sphere.
  mod_bool = ob.modifiers.new('my_bool_mod', 'BOOLEAN')
  # Set the mode of the modifier to DIFFERENCE.
  mod_bool.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
  # Set the object to be used by the modifier.

  mod_bool.object =  bpy.data.objects[name[i-1]] 

  # Set the name[i] as the active object.
  bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[name[i]]

  # Apply the modifier.
  res = bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier = 'my_bool_mod')
```

Accordingly, the script can be subdivided into the following sections:

In the first part, I define the materials of the shell, and their sizes.

In the second part, I create the spheres, from the smallest to the largest one, but the sequence has no importance.

Till here, the script works perfectly.

In the third part, I want to make the difference between the largest sphere and the one slightly smaller, i.e., I substract from the i^th sphere the (i-1)^th one. 
However, it seems to me that the line

```
      bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[name[i]]
```

does not work as I suppose, as the result of the script is a series of concentric spheres, but the boolean difference was applied only once on sphere4 using sphere3. Nothing was done on the other spheres. Moreover, three non applied operators for sphere 4 are still there (see screenshot).

So, here comes the question: what I am doing wrong? How can I select the active object from the name list on which the boolean modifiers is applied with the object selected from the same list?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In your final loop you are adding a boolean modifier to `ob`, which is the last object you created in the previous loop, then making `bpy.data.objects[name[i]]` the active object which the apply modifier operator will be used on, as they aren't the same object the operator will not apply the modifier you expect. Of note, using `mod_bool.name` would overcome any renaming issues from adding a second modifier with an existing name.

But, fixing that loop will not give you the result you are after. When you add the second modifier it will boolean the difference with the new sphere, which is smaller than the one you just cut out of the middle and will not be intersecting with the existing shell.

I think the way to get the result you want is to replace the final loop with -

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern='sphere*')
bpy.ops.object.join()
```

This will join all the spheres into one object, giving you the layers you are after.

Comment: Thanks, what I did not realize, was that

    mod_bool = ob.modifiers.new('my_bool_mod', 'BOOLEAN')

works always on ob, regarless which is the active object. The script does exactly what I need, when, in front of this line I add: ob = bpy.data.objects[name[i]]. 

Your suggestion worked as well, but resulted in a series of two-dimensional shells, without thickness; while I was looking for a series of concentric shells, whose thickness is given by the difference of radii.